# A super-linear time problem in NL

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, automata-theory, logspace

It is a well-known fact that $ \mathsf{NL} = \cup_{k>0} \mathsf{2NFA[k]} $, where $ \mathsf{2NFA[k]} $ is the class of languages recognized by two-way nondeterministic finite automata with $ k>0 $ input heads, shortly 2nfa(k).

I have two but similar questions:

Is there any known language in $ \mathsf{NL} $ requiring super-linear time, where the model is a standard space-bounded NTM having a read-only input tape and a read/write work tape?

Is there any known language recognized by some 2nfa(k) in super-linear time but not recognized by any 2nfa(k) in linear time?

Comment: I think both your questions are the same question. Do you have a reason for them being different, or are you just unsure?

Comment: @LukeMathieson: I am not sure whether for a given $ t(n) $ time bounded NTM, there exists an equivalent $ O(t(n)) $ time bounded 2nfa(k) for some $ k>0 $, and vice versa.

Comment: From the equivalence though, you know that every language  in NL has a 2nfa(k) and that every language that has a 2nfa(k) is in NL.

Comment: @LukeMathieson: Yes!

Comment: In the first question, you wrote "requiring super-linear time," but in which computational model?

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: Thank you for your comment. I edited the text.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that the "state of the art" is that it is extremely hard to prove superlinear lower bounds even for NP-complete problems. If you're fine with conditional lower bounds, then the field of *fine-grained complexity* gives you many problems that are in P but require superlinear time under some assumptions. In this [survey of fine-grained complexity](https://people.csail.mit.edu/virgi/eccentri.pdf) there are several such problems and some of them are in NL (for example there is an obvious NL algorithm for "Detecting if an edge-weighted graph has a triangle of negative total edge weight").